# Activity Indicator Doesn't Stop/Start Properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

EDIT: Problem Solved!
For others, To fix it, simply right click the WebView, click the "delegate" circle, and drag it to "File's Owner" on the left side.

Thanks for the help

--I'm fairly new to app developing, I'm in my first semester actually. Since it's a brand new course, the instructor knows very little as well. Therefore I have complete permission to ask for help on this. Thanks!

On to my question...

I want to include an activity indicator in my app as my WebView starts and stops loading, simply enough. At this point, it will animate. However, my problem is that it starts before the WebView starts loading anything, and also doesn't ever stop. My current code is this:

```
 - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
 [activity startAnimating];
 }
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[activity stopAnimating];
```

Other than that, I have it set up in the header...

```
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activity;
```

And as far as I can tell, set up rather properly. Oh, also, I do have "Animated" checked and "Hide When Stopped" checked in the .xib file.

UPDATE: NSLogs and breakpoints show that the methods aren't being called.

I am a highly visual learner, so, I will need to see what I am missing, unless it is a problem in the interface. Thanks...

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have your webView correctly connected to the delegate?  Toss in an NSLog or a couple breakpoints and make sure that your functions are being called.

Comment: I'll try that. I'll be back in a minute with details

Comment: I've added both, and got nothing. They simply aren't getting called. How do I resolve it? Thanks

Comment: I think that Dancreek got it right with respect to setting the delegate. Have you specifically set the delegate for your webview? If you can't answer that, then you probably haven't. Just option click from the webview in IB to "Files Owner" and select delegate. I think it will work after that.

Comment: Thanks, you guys are a great help. I don't recall it, but I'm not sure. I'll look into it

Comment: You, sir, are fantastic. That's exactly what I was missing.

Comment: Sorry it seamed so trivial to you guys probably, but, as a beginner I haven't fully observed what it does, and how that specifically works. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can put a break point in your code to see if the webViewDidFinishLoading is called. I'm guessing it is not being called. There is another delegate methods you should implement (see [UIWebViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate)), called `webView:didFailLoadWithError:`. Implement that and put a break point inside it. Let us know what happens.

Comment: I added breakpoints and logs, and I've gotten nothing. It seems as though they simply aren't getting called properly.

Comment: What should I do next? Sorry, as I don't have a large amount of experience in troubleshooting. Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking... am I supposed to attach the webView and activity indicator somehow? Or is it perhaps another problem.

Comment: That's a good start. Normally, this would mean the delegate is probably not set properly. But I am confused, since you say the activity indicator starts animating. Do you call startAnimating anywhere else?

Comment: Nope, in fact, I just removed the startAnimating entirely, and it still begins animation immediately when opening the app, and it doesn't stop. What might I be able to do to discover what's missing? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the apple developer examples? 
[Apple Developer Example Webview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html)